# highcharts not plotting json string containing x,y pairs (string, float). how to fix?

Tags: highcharts, getjson

I just switch from jqplot to highcharts, because i couldn't find an answer for my problem with jqplot.

My problem:
I want to plot the following result from a json string. this string contains out of datapairs in the following format: `yyyy00kw` (year with 4digits, 00 for padding, weeknumber 2digits) and a value (could be formated to float).
because the `x` value of the pair could change to `yyyymmdd` (year month day) or `yyyywwdd` (year week day) it has to be a string.

My json string contains the following:

```
[
  [
    ["20050043",12.800000190735],
    ["20050044",17.39999961853],
    ["20050045",10.10000038147],
    ["20050046",5.9000000953674],
    ["20050048",4.6999998092651],
    ["20050049",9.8999996185303],
    ["20050050",9.1999998092651],
    ["20050051",8.3999996185303],
    ["20050052",2.0999999046326],
    ["20060001",2.7000000476837],
    ["20060002",-1.1000000238419],
    ["20060004",2],
    ["20060005",4.9000000953674],
    ["20060006",6.8000001907349],
    ["20060007",6.0999999046326],
    ["20060009",4.3000001907349],
    ["20060010",3.4000000953674],
    ["20060011",8.1999998092651],
    ["20060012",7],
    ["20060017",11.60000038147],
    ["20060018",21.60000038147],
    ["20060019",24.799999237061],
    ["20060020",16.700000762939],
    ["20060021",0],
    ["20060022",0],
    ["20060024",0],
    ["20060025",18.10000038147],
    ["20060026",20.200000762939],
    ["20060052",2.9000000953674],
    ["20070001",0],
    ["20070019",0],
    ["20070020",0],
    ["20070024",0],
    ["20070025",0],
    ["20070026",0],
    ["20070027",0],
    ["20070028",0],
    ["20070029",0],
    ["20070030",0],
    ["20070031",0],
    ["20070032",0],
    ["20070033",0],
    ["20070034",0],
    ["20070035",0],
    ["20070036",0],
    ["20070037",0],
    ["20070038",0],
    ["20070039",0],
    ["20070040",0],
    ["20070041",0],
    ["20070042",0],
    ["20070043",0],
    ["20070044",0],
    ["20070045",0],
    ["20070046",0],
    ["20070047",0],
    ["20070048",0],
    ["20070049",0],
    ["20070050",0],
    ["20070051",0],
    ["20070052",0],
    ["20080001",0],
    ["20080002",0],
    ["20080003",0],
    ["20080004",0],
    ["20080005",0],
    ["20080006",0],
    ["20080007",0],
    ["20080008",0],
    ["20080009",0],
    ["20080010",0],
    ["20080012",0],
    ["20080013",0],
    ["20080017",0],
    ["20080018",0],
    ["20080019",0],
    ["20080020",0],
    ["20080021",0],
    ["20080022",0],
    ["20080023",0],
    ["20080024",0],
    ["20080025",0],
    ["20080026",0],
    ["20080027",0],
    ["20080028",0],
    ["20080029",0],
    ["20080030",0],
    ["20080031",0],
    ["20080034",0],
    ["20080035",0],
    ["20080036",0],
    ["20080037",0],
    ["20080038",0],
    ["20080039",0],
    ["20080040",0],
    ["20080041",0],
    ["20080042",0],
    ["20080043",0],
    ["20080044",0],
    ["20080045",0],
    ["20080046",0],
    ["20080047",0],
    ["20080048",0],
    ["20080049",0],
    ["20080050",0],
    ["20080051",0],
    ["20080052",0],
    ["20090001",0],
    ["20090002",0],
    ["20090003",0],
    ["20090004",0],
    ["20090005",0],
    ["20090006",0],
    ["20090024",0],
    ["20090025",0],
    ["20090026",0],
    ["20090028",0],
    ["20090029",0],
    ["20090030",0],
    ["20090031",0],
    ["20090032",0],
    ["20090033",0],
    ["20090034",0],
    ["20090035",0],
    ["20090036",0],
    ["20090037",0],
    ["20090038",0],
    ["20090039",0],
    ["20090040",0],
    ["20090041",0],
    ["20090042",0],
    ["20090043",0],
    ["20090044",0],
    ["20090045",0],
    ["20090046",0],
    ["20090047",0],
    ["20090048",0],
    ["20090049",0],
    ["20090050",0],
    ["20090051",0],
    ["20090052",0],
    ["20090053",0],
    ["20100001",0],
    ["20100002",0],
    ["20100003",0],
    ["20100004",0],
    ["20100005",0],
    ["20100006",0],
    ["20100007",0],
    ["20100008",0],
    ["20100009",0],
    ["20100010",0],
    ["20100011",0],
    ["20100012",0],
    ["20100013",0],
    ["20100014",0],
    ["20100015",0],
    ["20100016",0],
    ["20100017",0],
    ["20100018",0],
    ["20100019",0],
    ["20100020",0],
    ["20100021",0],
    ["20100022",0],
    ["20100023",0],
    ["20100024",0],
    ["20100025",0],
    ["20100026",0],
    ["20100027",0],
    ["20100028",0],
    ["20100029",0],
    ["20100030",0],
    ["20100031",0],
    ["20100032",0],
    ["20100033",0],
    ["20100034",0],
    ["20100035",0],
    ["20100036",0],
    ["20100037",0],
    ["20100038",0],
    ["20100039",0],
    ["20100040",0],
    ["20100041",0],
    ["20100042",0],
    ["20100043",0],
    ["20100044",0],
    ["20100045",0],
    ["20100046",0],
    ["20100047",0],
    ["20100048",0],
    ["20100049",0],
    ["20100050",0],
    ["20100051",0],
    ["20100052",0],
    ["20100053",0],
    ["20110001",0],
    ["20110002",0],
    ["20110003",0],
    ["20110004",0],
    ["20110005",0],
    ["20110006",0],
    ["20110007",0],
    ["20110008",0],
    ["20110009",0],
    ["20110010",0],
    ["20110014",0],
    ["20110015",0],
    ["20110016",0],
    ["20110017",0],
    ["20110018",0],
    ["20110019",0],
    ["20110020",0],
    ["20110021",0],
    ["20110022",0],
    ["20110023",0],
    ["20110024",0],
    ["20110025",0],
    ["20110026",0],
    ["20110027",0],
    ["20110028",0],
    ["20110029",0],
    ["20110030",0],
    ["20110031",0],
    ["20110032",0],
    ["20110033",0],
    ["20110034",0],
    ["20110035",0],
    ["20110036",0],
    ["20110039",0],
    ["20110043",0],
    ["20110044",0],
    ["20110045",0],
    ["20110046",0],
    ["20110047",0],
    ["20110048",0],
    ["20110049",0],
    ["20110052",0],
    ["20120001",0],
    ["20120002",0],
    ["20120003",0],
    ["20120004",0],
    ["20120005",0],
    ["20120006",0],
    ["20120007",0],
    ["20120009",0],
    ["20120010",0],
    ["20120013",0],
    ["20120014",0],
    ["20120015",0],
    ["20120016",0],
    ["20120017",0]
  ]
]
```

Here is my javascript code:

```
<script class="code" type="text/javascript">
  var data = [];
  var chart;
  $(document).ready(function() {
    //hier geht es los
    $.getJSON("120925_sql_bauen.php", function(json) {
      chart = new Highcharts.Chart({
        chart: {
          renderTo: 'chart1',
          type: 'line'
        },
        title: {
          text: 'Wetterdatenprojekt'
        },
        xAxis: {
          //categories: []
        },
        yAxis: {
          title: {
            text: 'aktuelle Wetterwerte'
          },
          plotLines: [{
            value: 0,
            width: 1
          }]
        },
        series: json
      });
    });
  });
</script>
```

Unfortunately highcharts shows no plot.
I hope, that highcharts doesn't have the same problem with strings then jqplot :-(

Comment: hello, i managed to plot exactly what i want. example in jsfiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/LExXK/ but why doesn't plot my original script? for me it looks like the one in jsfiddle?? good night, paul

Answer (score 3):

The problem is that you try to use your reply directly. You need to "remove" one layer of arrays. That is `data` should be `json[0]`

I updated my example: http://jsfiddle.net/GgNmY/2/

Regarding previous note that values should be numeric is only true for Y-axis (at least in earlier versions of Highcharts).

Edit: Here is to extract the data point (the values) and the categories.

```
var data = [];
var cats = [];
json[0].forEach(function(point){
    data.push(point[1]);
    cats.push(point[0]);
});
```

Here is an running example: http://jsfiddle.net/GgNmY/3/

Comment: hello, thanks for the answer, but i think that using numerical values in highcart is not always true. example  jsfiddle.net/LExXK uses strings for the x-axis and it works. Why that, if only numerical values should be used.
Any clues?

Best wishes and a free sunday!
Paul

here is the code:
   $(function () {
    $('#container').highcharts({
        xAxis: {
            minPadding: 1,
            maxPadding: 1
        },
        series: [{
            data: [
                ["First", 29.9],
                ["Second", 71.5],
                ["Third", 106.4]
            ]
        }]
    });
});

Comment: hello, thanks. your answer regarding the json[0] display my plotting. it helps!

unfortunately my values for the x-axis aren't displayed. they are displayed inside each point, if i move over it.
how could these values be displayed on x-axis?
i suppose that categories are the catchword, but i don't want to get an extra json string for the categories.
is it possible, to extract catogories from my json? e.g. extracting the x-value from each pair?

best wishes
paul

Comment: I updated my answer, and added a new example. Please specify your question better in the future so it is clear what you want to achieve.

Answer (score 0):

In Highchart, you can set your series : [data](http://api.highcharts.com/highcharts#series.data) object in the form of the JSON input.
In such a case, if the JSON input is in the form:

```
[
[1,12],
[2,5],
[3,18],
....
[10,22]
]
```

Then the following attribute can be added in the chart definition:

```
series:[{
       data: json
}]
```

Here is the running [JSFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/saikatkumarde/01h9j1n2/1/) example